# DataFrames.jl : count rows by group while defining count column name

Tags: dataframe, julia

I am trying to count the number of rows by group in a DataFrame. The following code generates a new column, called x1, which which has the intended information:

```
by(df, [:grouping_var_1, :grouping_var_2], nrow)
```

However, I am not aware on how to generate such column in a way I can define a name other than x1. The solution I have found so far is:

```
@pipe df |> by(_, [:grouping_var_1, :grouping_var_2], nrow) |> rename(_, :x1 => :my_desired_name);
```

Is there anyway I could do this directly without having to use rename ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please update DataFrames.jl to 0.21 version.

Then use:

```
combine(groupby(df, [:grouping_var_1, :grouping_var_2]], nrow => :my_desired_name)
```

Two comments:

- `by` is deprecated and you are recommended not to use it (you can see the warning if you start Julia with `--depwarn=true`)
- A general pattern for writing transofrmations is `source_columns => function => target_column_name`, you can use a shorthand `source_columns => function`, in which case the name of the target column is generated automatically. A special case is `nrow` (without anything) and `nrow => target_column_name`, as for `nrow` you do not have to pass the source columns for convenience