# MethodError: no method matching groupby(::DataFrame, ::Vector{Symbol}, ::Pair{typeof(nrow), Symbol})

Tags: dataframe, count, julia, grouping

I am trying to use the code of this question: [DataFrames.jl : count rows by group while defining count column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63330210/dataframes-jl-count-rows-by-group-while-defining-count-column-name) where I would like to count the number of rows per group. Here is some reproducible code:

```
using DataFrames

df = DataFrame(group = ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"],
               subgroup = ["X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y"])

12×2 DataFrame
 Row │ group   subgroup 
     │ String  String   
─────┼──────────────────
   1 │ A       X
   2 │ A       X
   3 │ A       X
   4 │ A       Y
   5 │ A       Y
   6 │ A       Y
   7 │ B       X
   8 │ B       X
   9 │ B       Y
  10 │ B       Y
  11 │ B       Y
  12 │ B       Y
```

When running the following code:

```
combine(groupby(df, [:group, :subgroup], nrow => :n))
```

Returns this error:

```
MethodError: no method matching groupby(::DataFrame, ::Vector{Symbol}, ::Pair{typeof(nrow), Symbol})
Closest candidates are:
  groupby(::AbstractDataFrame, ::Any; sort, skipmissing) at ~/.julia/packages/DataFrames/JZ7x5/src/groupeddataframe/groupeddataframe.jl:211

Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ In[51]:1
 [2] eval
   @ ./boot.jl:368 [inlined]
 [3] include_string(mapexpr::typeof(REPL.softscope), mod::Module, code::String, filename::String)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1428
```

I am not sure why this error happens while running the same code. So I was wondering if anyone could explain why this happens and if this is the right way to count the number of rows per group in `Julia`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've just got the brackets wrong:

```
combine(groupby(df, [:group, :subgroup]), nrow => :n)
```

Note the first closing parens before `nrow` - this is the call to `groupby`, and it is the result of this which you pass as the first argument to `combine`

Comment: You got it! So I update my answer as an additional way to do the same.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the [Nil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74912804/11747148), you can also use the following syntax:

```
combine(groupby(df, [:group, :subgroup]), :group => length => :nrow)
# 4×3 DataFrame
#  Row │ group   subgroup  nrow
#      │ String  String    Int64
# ─────┼─────────────────────────
#    1 │ A       X             3
#    2 │ A       Y             3
#    3 │ B       X             2
#    4 │ B       Y             4
```

In the above, I'm counting `nrows` per `:group` and the subsequent `:subgroup`. The first row of the result tells me the number of samples (rows) that have the A group label along with the X subgroup label.

*If you think this can't be implied as a different syntax, please tell me; I'll delete this answer.

Comment: `x -> length(x)` can be just `length`

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński, Thanks! I'll apply it.